# how to convert any type of date pattern according to Locale in android?

Tags: android, date, locale

I have to convert date pattern whatever we provide as input but date format should come in according to Locale like: ("dd MM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()) but output should be(MM dd, yyyy for US) according to Locale.US, Locale.FRANCE, Locale.CANADA etc...

Rightnow I am doing.

```
Locale ll = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
String datePattern1 = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(ll, "yyyy/MM/dd");

Log.i("TAG", "After : "+new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern1).format(date));
```

Comment: did you try java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String s = dateFormat.format(date);

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)
Class which formats the date according to user Locale.  here is the example code :

```
String myDob= "16/01/1989";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = null;
try {
date = sdf.parse(myDob);
} catch (ParseException e) {
// handle exception here !
}
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =   android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String s = dateFormat.format(date);
```